# QGIS measure tool does not continue to measure within point symbol

Tags: qgis, distance, measurements

We are using QGIS more and more, however, today a colleague noticed something strange when using the measure line tool.

We have point features and different symbols of different sizes and colors are stacked on each other to provide all the information for quality control. One of the main aspects is position and therefore the distance between points and of the points with respect to our framework data (streets, lots, etc.).

When measuring distance, the rubberband tool stops measuring when entering the area of the point symbol, which at display scales of ca. 1:350, can represent around 4 m.

Does someone know how to correct this?